Use script output with quotes as commandline arguments
I want to write a script that generates commandline arguments for another program.
Until know I have written a script that simply echo the arguments and use it in the following way:
external_program $(generate arguments)

This stops working as soon as the generated arguments require quotes. To be clear what I mean: The resulting function call should be equivalent to
external_program "First argument with spaces" "Second argument with spaces"

How can I write and call a script to achieve such behavior?
EDIT: The things that I cam change is the exact commandline to connect the output of generate with the input of external_program (which should be short because that is something that I will have to type in) and the generate script which can be as complex as required to do the job.
EDIT: The duplicates does not match my problem because I already know how to pass all input arguments to another script and I know how to print variables, but my question is how I can get the output of one program copied over to the input of another program, so that quotes string  stay as one input argument of the second program.
EDIT2: "input of another program" was bad phrasing. What I actually mean was commandline arguments of another program.

how does generate arguments work? what does it return?

I write the generate script, so it can work in any way that solves the problem.

I'd make generate print each argument in a different line, then you can pass that to xargs.

So you mean something like "generate | xargs external_program"? That is not the way I would like it to work, but I will test it, and accept it, if it works in my case.

FWIW, external_program $(generate arguments) is subject to word-splitting and glob-expansion, so it is a broken method that you should never use.

Under [tag:bash] you could either use printf 'Arg: %q\n' "$argument" or echo "Argument: ${arg@Q}"!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I do not understand your comment. In the question is no print at all, so ffor whoch situation I should use that and why?

Just try: printf 'Argunent: %q\n' $(./generate)!

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub How could printf %q $(generate) solve the problem? I do not want to print some variable but want to pass it to another script. Or do you mean that it works if I use printf inside the generate script?

how I can get the output of one program copied over to the input of another use pipes program1 | program2. For using output of a commend as argument to another command, then answer is in mentioned duplicates.

For parsing ./generate, use mapfile -t argArray < <(./generate), then ./yourTool "${argArray[@]}".

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub I have not tested it yet, but I think that could work, but the xargs seems shorter and clearer to me.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub "then answer is in mentioned duplicates": I have looked at them but I can not find where my special situation (arguments with spaces) is answered in any of them.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

Your question implie two differents things (step):

parsing output of ./generate
running a command with array variable as quoted arguments.
Then


mapfile -t argArray < <(./generate)




./yourTool "${argArray[@]}"
All this is explained in mentioned duplicates.




You can use xargs to achieve that.
Write generate so it outputs each argument delimited by a null character:
#!/bin/sh
# File: generate
printf 'argument1\0'
printf 'argument 2\0'
printf 'argument"3\0'

Then you can just do ./generate | xargs -0 external_program.
Example:
#!/bin/sh
# File: print_args
for arg in "$@"; do
        echo "Argument: '$arg'"
done

$ ./generate | xargs -0 ./print_args
Argument: 'argument1'
Argument: 'argument 2'
Argument: 'argument"3'

This will work regardless of the characters the arguments contain, whitespace or not (except for NUL, of course).

What if $argument do contain an single quote?  Under [tag:bash] you could either use printf 'Argunent: %q\n' "$argument" or echo "Argument: ${arg@Q}"!

Someting like printf 'Argunent: %q\n' $(generate)  (without xargs)

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub What would be the problem if any of the variables contain a single quote? I do not know which variable to you mean but I do not see a problem with any.

@F.Hauri-GiveUpGitHub This code has no issues with single quotes.
